# Model is not binding when submitting form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Alright I've been with this issue for 2 days. For simplicity I'll write code as less as possible.
I'm using the same controller both for viewing and saving data. My domain class, view, controller are as follows (I'm having issue with the last prop `public DateTime CreatedOn`, the whole problem is explained at the end so you can skip to it first):

Domain Class:

```
public partial class Admin_TestCategory
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public short TestCategoryId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [Required]
    public string TestCategoryName { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int? CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 3)]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model BOL.Entities.Admin.Admin_TestCategory
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit Category";
    Layout = "~/Views/Admin/_Admin.cshtml";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditTestCategory", "Admin", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Edit Category</legend>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TestCategoryId)
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.TestCategoryName, "Category Name :", new {@class = "col-lg-2"})
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TestCategoryName, new {@class = "col-lg-3 form-control"})
                    <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CreatedBy, "Created By :", new {@class = "col-lg-2"})
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CreatedBy, new {@class = "col-lg-3 form-control"})
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-group col-lg-2">Update</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="row">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CreatedOn, "Created On :", new {@class = "col-lg-4"})
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CreatedOn, "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", new {Name = Html.NameFor(m => m.CreatedOn), @class = "col-lg-6 form-control datepicker" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

and the Controller:

```
    // GET /Admin/EditTestCategory
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult EditTestCategory(Admin_TestCategory newTestCategory)
    {
        var testCatService = new TestCategoryService();
        var oldTestCategory = testCatService.GetById(newTestCategory.TestCategoryId);

        //check if that category exists or not
        //category does not exist
        if (oldTestCategory == null)
            return HttpNotFound("Can not find the ID of the given Test Category");

        //category exists
        return View(oldTestCategory);
    }

    // POST /Admin/UpdateTestCategory
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateTestCategory(Admin_TestCategory newTestCategory)
    {
        var testCatService = new TestCategoryService();
        var oldTestCategory = testCatService.GetById(newTestCategory.TestCategoryId);

        //check if that category exists or not
        //category does not exist
        if (oldTestCategory == null)
            return HttpNotFound("Can not find the ID of the given Test Category");

        //category exists
        //check if the new data is changed or not
        //data is not changed
        var o = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oldTestCategory);
        var n = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newTestCategory);
        if (o == n)
            return RedirectToAction("TestCategory", "Admin");

        //data is changed
        testCatService.UpdateTestCategory(newTestCategory);
        return RedirectToAction("TestCategory", "Admin");
    }
```

How the controller works is all written with comments. The way it works is, when this controller is hit for first time it will only have the id property then it will fetch other data using that property and fill the View. Then when I hit the button of my view this controller's parameter will have all the changed data and hence it will update database. The only problem is when the controller is hit for 2nd time, it gets all the other data through model binding but only the last one `CreatedOn` which is a `DateTime`. I provided `Name` attribute to make sure it binds the model but it doesn't, in the controller the date becomes reset, although in the browser I inspected it and yes it has the exact Name that it needs.

I tried to make this form `POST`, tried to add attribute `[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]` in the DateTime prop in my domain class but it doesn't work because in view its a `TextBoxFor` and I need it that way for auto validation. So what else should I try?

**UPDATE**

I have split the controller in 2, one for showing all data using `GET` another for updating all data using `POST`. Still same problem.

Comment: you mentioned you are using same controller for view and edit. post complete controller code with action verbs..easy to find out where its going wrong!

Comment: my controller is currently using `[HttpGet]`. are you suggesting i should make another copy with `[HttpPost]` for saving?

Comment: Yes. you need [HttpPost] for saving your data

Comment: did that. still same problem.

Comment: Post the complete controller code

Comment: updated it, please check.

Comment: Are you returning a DateTime type in your post or just a string? You might have to do a type conversion before you can save the value to the backend.

Comment: Well I am not quite sure about it. In the `TextBoxFor` the `m => m.CreatedOn` is to bind and the `"{0:dd-MM-yyyy}"` is to format and display right? Where do I write the code to convert it?

Comment: Why do you have `CreatedBy` and `CreatedOn` - those properties are not appropriate in your view, and certainly should not be edited by a user. You set those properties in the POST method immediately before you save your object (based on the current user and `DateTime.Now`)

Answer (score 1):

Add Below code to your Post action it will helpful to findout which field is causing error.

I tried executing your code on my machine and it seems error with "Date" format. try using `"{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"`; format in your code it will resolve your error.

```
   foreach (ModelState modelState in ViewData.ModelState.Values)
   {
      foreach (ModelError error in modelState.Errors)
      {
        var errorMsg = error.ErrorMessage;
      }
   }
```

Happy Coding :)

**Updated:** Add DisplayFormat attribute in ur model property as it is in ur view  code

Comment: wow man you taught me new way of debugging. alright I have done that and it says `The value '18/04/2018' is not valid for CreatedOn.` any ideas why? because `CreatedOn` is a DateTime property.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Pls accept ans if it resolve ur issue

Comment: no mate it didn't resolve my issue it just helped me find out the error. but i need to know why is this happening and how to solve it.

Comment: Add DisplayFormat attribute on ur Date property in model as it is ur view code

Comment: newTestCategory.CreatedOn = (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request["CreatedOn"])) ? DateTime.ParseExact(Request["CreatedOn"].Trim(), "dd/MM/yyyy", null) : newTestCategory.CreatedOn; Try using this work around to get "CreatedOn"

Answer (score 0):

as per the comments, You need to have a separate GET and POST action.  On the Get action you need to find the item you want to edit and return it as a View Model:

```
 public ActionResult EditTestCategory(short id)
    {
        var testCatService = new TestCategoryService();
        var categoryToEdit = testCatService.GetById(id);

        //check if that category exists or not
        //category does not exist
        if (categoryToEdit == null)
            return HttpNotFound("Can not find the ID of the given Test Category");

        return View(categoryToEdit);
    }
```

Then you need a POST action that accepts the edited model like so:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditTestCategory(Admin_TestCategory viewModel)
    {
        var testCatService = new TestCategoryService();
        Admin_TestCategory categoryToEdit = testCatService.GetById(viewModel.TestCategoryId);

        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            categoryToEdit.TestCategoryName = viewModel.TestCategoryName;
            categoryToEdit.CreatedBy = viewModel.CreatedBy;
            //etc
            testCatService.UpdateTestCategory(categoryToEdit);

        }

        return RedirectToAction("TestCategory", "Admin");
    }
```

The other issue you have is that CreatedBy is data type int? in Admin_TestCategory.cs

In your view you're using:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CreatedBy, new { @class = "col-lg-3 form-control" })
```

If you change to:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.CreatedBy, new { @class = "col-lg-3 form-control" })
```

Model Binds Fine

Comment: yes I did that but still same problem. please check my updated post. also the `ModelState.IsValid` returns `false` as only one property is not binding in the model.

Comment: this doesn't provide any solution to OP's question

Comment: This solution Does work - don't understand the down vote reason why it's not binding the one property is that in Admin_TestCategory.cs you've got created by as data type int and in the view you're using TextBoxFor instead of editorFor.   I'll update answer